# Commandname multiple

Tags: asp.net

I've an ASP.NET form view with multiple forms. I want to use only a single button and get rid of the rest. I assume then I need to somehow call the command for multiple forms on the update, i.e command name.

1. Is it possible to do this declaratively?
2. How would I do this programatically?

Comment: More Detail ASP.NET WebForms or ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: @Anthony this is Webforms. I'm pretty sure I can grab the control and execute the command in program but more curious about the declarative case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For #2, I can use Form.UpdateItem() command. I'm still waiting for #1, if I can assign multiple command names to a button or anything like that.

Also if anyone show a different way to do this I will give credit for the answer.